# Stream an audio from server to my app

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I want to stream an audio from the server to Android App. I found some solutions but my scenario is quite different.

I have an audio file which is uploaded to the server, I want to run that audio on a specific time and must be stop after audio complete. 
Now let say a user opens his android app to listen an audio after one minute from the start time of that audio than he must listen audio from after one minute of audio running and could not listen that audio from back and forward.

Please guide me the to do it and which technologies should I use?
Would it be better you use Google Firebase or any Realtime server? or simple hosting will be a nice option ?
Thanks

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/implement-audio-streaming-in-android-applications-8758d3bc62f1 you can see this link. Just pause audio after 1 minute

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking honestly... can you describe your app more?